# Mysql Date Format in Java

Tags: java, mysql, date, date-format

I have a website which supplies date in 2 formats: `28th June 2009` or `June 2009`.

Now I would like to convert both of these into the same format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` using MySQL and Java.

`SimpleDateFormat` gives an error: "Unparsable Date". What's the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `June 2009` as you can not say its a date you need to make it a date by adding a day in this month-year format. Ex.. add first day of month here and make it `1 June 2009` then parse it in desired format.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

       public class Test {

          public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException 
          { 
              String dateStr = "28 June 2009";
              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
              System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(dateStr)));
          }
   }
```

Comment: new Date(url) <--- What is the 'url' ?

Comment: june 2009 is ok... but what about 28th june 2009? how does SimpleDateFormat detect the 'th' after the day? if it way simply '28 June 2009' i would have used the Parse method in SimpleDateFormat...

Comment: and isn't Date(str) a deprecated method now?

Comment: yes `Date(str)` is deprecated you can use Calendar for that. And `28th` is and string just remove `th` from it and move further.

Comment: yep...that's what i'm doing...was just looking for a more efficient way using just the SimpleDateFormat and no String manipulations...anyways thanks